# How to find bucket size from N1Q1 in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I don't want to use rest API to find bucket size of **couchbase**. Is there any N1Q1 to find disk-used by bucket or keyspace?

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but you can use CURL from a N1QL query - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/curl.html

Comment: thanks @Matthew, I am using client certificate "mandatory" and  secure rest APIs are blocked when I make it "Mandatory". Not able to connect thru rest calls. So I changed all rest calls in n1q1 but I am not able to find n1q1 for bucket size.

Comment: I think it's going to be tricky, because documents are compressed on disk. Certainly you can get the JSON size of anything you query, but that would basically require you to query *everything*, which is probably not a good idea, and it would probably be much larger than actual disk usage. Therefore, it would require a special system function to do it efficiently and correctly, and I don't think there is one (at least not one that's documented). I'm curious to know the use case: maybe you can submit a feature request  on issues.couchbase.com

Answer (score 1):

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-41655, merging it now, will be available in 7.0....